# Confirm deletion alert code not quite right

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a simple todo app in JS and i've added an alert box to confirm deletion when usr clicks the delete button. If user clicks 'OK' it deletes fine, and if clicked 'Cancel' it won't delete but it creates another empty 
li tag under it.

Something is not quite right with my deleteItem function but I can't figure out what, tried adding an else statement same thing happens. Any help with an explanation will be greatly appreciate (I'm a noob in JS as you can tell). Thanks!

```js
//grab form id first
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let OurList = document.getElementById("ourList");

 //on submit event from user, do something
ourForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) =>{
  //will prevent alert appearing on any click event around form, ONLY when submit button is clicked.
    e.preventDefault();
    //access value of user input as a test
    //console.log(ourField.value);

  //now on submit we're gonna pass the function below which is created further down and takes one argument and its value:
    if(ourField.value === ""){
      alert("Please add a task")
    }else{
      createItem(ourField.value);
    }
})

function createItem(item) {
    let createdHTML = `<li>${item} <button 
    onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", createdHTML);

  //clear the inpur field value after user input:
    ourField.value = "";

  //keep field focused after clearing 
    ourField.focus();
}

function deleteItem(itemToDelete){
    //create alert
    let result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (result === true) {
    //Logic to delete the item
    itemToDelete.parentElement.remove();
    ourField.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Todo App</h1>
<form id="ourForm">
  <input id = "ourField" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <button> Create item</button>

  <h3>To do tasks:</h3>
  <ul id="ourList">
  </ul>
```

Comment: _“and if clicked 'Cancel' it won't delete but it creates another empty li tag under it”_ - when I run your snippet, I can’t reproduce that … I don’t see any empty LI showing up anywhere.

Comment: For me too it seems working perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to change is: make the buttons of the list items of type `button`. They default value of `type` for a button is `submit`, which will submit the whole form, which will trigger your issue.

```js
//grab form id first
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let OurList = document.getElementById("ourList");

 //on submit event from user, do something
ourForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) =>{
  //will prevent alert appearing on any click event around form, ONLY when submit button is clicked.
    e.preventDefault();
    //access value of user input as a test
    //console.log(ourField.value);

  //now on submit we're gonna pass the function below which is created further down and takes one argument and its value:
    if(ourField.value === ""){
      alert("Please add a task")
    }else{
      createItem(ourField.value);
    }
})

function createItem(item) {
    let createdHTML = `<li>${item} <button 
    onclick="deleteItem(this)" type="button">Delete</button></li>`;
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", createdHTML);

  //clear the inpur field value after user input:
    ourField.value = "";

  //keep field focused after clearing 
    ourField.focus();
}

function deleteItem(itemToDelete){
    //create alert
    let result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (result === true) {
    //Logic to delete the item
    itemToDelete.parentElement.remove();
    ourField.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Todo App</h1>
<form id="ourForm">
  <input id = "ourField" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <button> Create item</button>

  <h3>To do tasks:</h3>
  <ul id="ourList">
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the `form` tag after the button, as a result your `ourForm` listener gets called even for confirmation box.

```js
//grab form id first
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let OurList = document.getElementById("ourList");

 //on submit event from user, do something
ourForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) =>{
  //will prevent alert appearing on any click event around form, ONLY when submit button is clicked.
    e.preventDefault();
    //access value of user input as a test
    //console.log(ourField.value);

  //now on submit we're gonna pass the function below which is created further down and takes one argument and its value:
    if(ourField.value === ""){
      alert("Please add a task")
    }else{
      createItem(ourField.value);
    }
})

function createItem(item) {
    let createdHTML = `<li>${item} <button 
    onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", createdHTML);

  //clear the inpur field value after user input:
    ourField.value = "";

  //keep field focused after clearing 
    ourField.focus();
}

function deleteItem(itemToDelete){
    //create alert
    let result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (result === true) {
    //Logic to delete the item
    itemToDelete.parentElement.remove();
    ourField.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Todo App</h1>
<form id="ourForm">
  <input id = "ourField" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <button> Create item</button>
</form>

  <h3>To do tasks:</h3>
  <ul id="ourList">
  </ul>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out! Indeed I forgot the closing tag for the form.